# Disable css animation on page load

Tags: css

I want to disable css animation on page load only.

The thing is that this css animation is the menu icon of main navigation menu, but when on subpages (where there also is a submenu present) on click on submenu the main menu animation activates - but i would like it to only start when my main navigation icon is clicked. I provided html, javascript and css involved.

I would appreciate your support in this.

html:

```
<div class="mcwrap">
    <input id="click" name="exit" type="checkbox">
    <label for="click"><span class="burger"></span></label>     
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$('.mcwrap label').on('click', function(){
        (!$('#click').prop('checked')) ? setTimeout(function(){opensLeft()}, 200) : setTimeout(function(){closesLeft()}, 200);              
});

function opensLeft() {
    $("#sl").addClass('visible')
    $("#swipe").addClass('isOpenLeft');
}

function closesLeft() {
    $("#sl").removeClass('visible')
    $("#swipe").removeClass('isOpenLeft');
}
```

css:

```
#sl.visible, #sr.visible {
  display: block;
}
.mcwrap {
  padding-top: 9px;
}
.mcwrap input {
  display: none;
}
.mcwrap label {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
}
/* Exit Icon */
.mcwrap label:before,
.mcwrap input:checked + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #fafafa;
}
.mcwrap label:before {
  -webkit-animation: animationOneReverse 1s ease forwards;
  animation: animationOneReverse 1s ease forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animationOneReverse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes animationOneReverse {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(315deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
.mcwrap input:checked + label:before {
  -webkit-animation: animationOne 1s ease forwards;
  animation: animationOne 1s ease forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animationOne {
  0%,
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
  }
}
@keyframes animationOne {
  0%,
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(315deg);
  }
}
.mcwrap label:after,
.mcwrap input:checked + label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #fafafa;
}
.mcwrap label:after {
  -webkit-animation: animationTwoReverse 1s ease forwards;
  animation: animationTwoReverse 1 s ease forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animationTwoReverse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(405deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(450deg);
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes animationTwoReverse {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(405deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(450deg);
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
.mcwrap input:checked + label:after {
  -webkit-animation: animationTwo 1s ease forwards;
  animation: animationTwo 1s ease forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animationTwo {
  0%,
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(450deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(405deg);
  }
}
@keyframes animationTwo {
  0%,
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(450deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(405deg);
  }
}
/* Burger Icon */
.mcwrap label .burger:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #fafafa;
  -webkit-animation: animationBurgerTopReverse 1s ease forwards;
  animation: animationBurgerTopReverse 1s ease forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animationBurgerTopReverse {
  0%,
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(12px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  51% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(12px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes animationBurgerTopReverse {
  0%,
  50% {
    transform: translateY(12px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  51% {
    transform: translateY(12px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.mcwrap input:checked + label .burger:before {
  -webkit-animation: animationBurgerTop 1s ease forwards;
  animation: animationBurgerTop 1s ease forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animationBurgerTop {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(12px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  51%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(12px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes animationBurgerTop {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(12px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  51%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(12px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
.mcwrap label .burger:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #fafafa;
  -webkit-animation: animationBurgerBottomReverse 1s ease forwards;
  animation: animationBurgerBottomReverse 1s ease forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animationBurgerBottomReverse {
  0%,
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-12px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  51% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-12px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes animationBurgerBottomReverse {
  0%,
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-12px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  51% {
    transform: translateY(-12px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.mcwrap input:checked + label .burger:after {
  -webkit-animation: animationBurgerBottom 1s ease forwards;
  animation: animationBurgerBottom 1s ease forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animationBurgerBottom {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-12px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  51%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-12px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes animationBurgerBottom {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-12px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  51%,
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-12px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add in **JS** a class when document is loaded:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    $('body').addClass('loaded')
});
```

Then in **CSS**:

```
.loaded .mcwrap label:before {
  -webkit-animation: animationOneReverse 1s ease forwards;
  animation: animationOneReverse 1s ease forwards;
}
```

Repeat this example for every animation that need the `load` event

Comment: Thanks but the animation is still running on every page load with above

Comment: Can you fiddle your code with my suggestion? So I could understand.

Comment: I've added `.loaded` in prefix selector in CSS!

Comment: This: ??
    .loaded .mcwrap label:before {
      -webkit-animation: animationOneReverse 1s ease forwards;
      animation: animationOneReverse 1s ease forwards;
    }

Comment: Yes, you have to change your selector for those animations, we add the .load className when the document is loaded, so you can use it now to wait the load to apply your CSS

Comment: But when applying above solution the animation is still triggered everytime page loads??

Comment: That mean the page is loaded, what are you calling the "page loads"?

Comment: Yes I see - u may have taken a wrong approach to this question... I need the animation to stop running on page load. I mean, stop the initial animation in the css - not make it run when the page is ready - just stop the initial animation